# How to access WP REST API for WordPress.com sites?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I see WordPress.com recently started using Gutenberg, which relies on the WP REST API.
I'm building a plugin and I'd like to use the WP REST API from a self-hosted site, and have it communicate with a WordPress.com site, but I'm having trouble finding the REST API base URL.
For example, `https://cmljnelson.wordpress.com/wp-json` is a 404. [The documentation about REST API discovery](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/discovery/) doesn't seem to apply to WordPress.com.
How can I find the WP REST API base URL for WordPress.com sites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress.com's REST API apparently is shared among sites hosted there and you can access it here: https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/.

If you want access to the REST routes of a specific site in WordPress.com, use the `/sites` route:

`https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/{site-id or domain}/`

[image: WordPress.com REST API]

Further reading:

- [WordPress REST API on WordPress.com](https://developer.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/wordpress-rest-api-on-wordpress-com/).
- [WordPress.com REST API Resources](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/).
- [WordPress.com API Console](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/).

Comment: What is this `{site-id or domain}`? It gives me `Unknown blog` for my domain.

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for hours and I only see folks answering "it's enabled by default" when its not. (its enabled by default, yes, on localhost / self hosted project. Not on WordPress.com. There is no such thing like Settings > Permalink to make the wp-json path available)