# How to upload an image to wordpress.com through REST API in python

Tags: wordpress, http-post, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to upload an image to my wordpress.com site (not WP installed on my own site) using WordPress' REST API in python. There are a [few examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915184/how-to-upload-images-using-wordpress-rest-api-in-python) of how to do this on SO when the WordPress site is hosted by the user. But I could not find any example when the site is on wordpress.com. I tried to follow the example of a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344737/how-to-access-wp-rest-api-for-wordpress-com-sites) and used the code below. I tried  `url = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/' + domain + '/media'` as the access URL but got a 400 (malformed) response code.

I generated wp_token as

```
wordpress_credentials = wordpress_user + ':' + wordpress_password
wordpress_token = base64.b64encode(wordpress_credentials.encode())
wp_token = wordpress_token.decode('utf-8')
```

`wordpress_password` here is the app password.

How do I debug why I am getting the 400 response? Appreciate any help.

```
import json, os, subprocess
def wp_upload_image2(domain, wp_token, img_path):
# Form the url
    url = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/' + domain + '/media/new'

# Extract the filename and the extension from the img_path
   extension = img_path[img_path.rfind('.')+1 : len(img_path)]
   print("img_path: ", img_path, "Filename: ", img_path, "extension: ", extension)

# Now form the header
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'BEARER ' + wp_token,
    }

    try:
        with open(img_path, 'rb') as fp:
            print("Successfully opened file!")
            files = {
               'media[]': fp,
            }
            rs = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
            print("Response from WP: ", rs)
            return(rs)
        except IOError as e:
            print(f"Couldn't open file ({e})")
```